What am I missing when attaching this light switch?

I thought that I was embarking on what was going to be a very easy fix. Instead, I found that the light switches were apparently a homeowner special. I looked through the attached dimmer switch, and I thought that I had everything attached correctly, but only the left hand light switch is working right now. I position the picture so that the right hand one's terminal should be visible. Am I missing something obvious here? At this point, I'm considering calling in a local electrician, just to fix the wires behind it, which are a bit of a twisted mess.

This is basically the first electrical repair I have attempted in the house.

Hard to say what else may be going on, but a starting point is that your wire loops are going in the wrong direction - i.e., tightening the screws pushes the wire away, resulting in very poor connections. Highly recommend a better quality switch that lets you wire straight in such as this Leviton - basically $2 switches instead of $1 switches with "side wire".

I don’t want to sound like a jerk, but those really are terrible connections. And there’s what looks like a bare connection below the top right screw. These are ‘start a fire’ terrible. Take your time learning how to do these things right. And maybe get an electrician to fix this one.

I agree with @AloysiusDefenestrate the connections are awful and are hooked around the screws backward

You make good points. And I've found that, somehow, I've managed to cut electricity to parts of the master bedroom by this change in the switches (and no, switching either of them to on isn't restoring it). Tomorrow, when I have more daylight to work with, I'm going to shut off that breaker again and try fixing the loops (in my defense, they're really stiff copper wire), but I think I'm also going to call in an electrician because something must be routing through there that I managed to disrupt.

If you don’t already, get a multimeter, a non-contact voltage detector, and needlenose pliers (to close the awg12 wire loops). Bonus points for a torque screwdriver and decent wire stripper.

What you have done is mix up the incoming hot from the breaker box  ( that should also be tied into any pass through power wires) and the outgoing switched hot that activate the lights.  All are black, so easily confused.   Research online how this type of wiring is done and then try to decipher your wires.  Also heed others advice on attachment of wires and procurement of tools.

Tip: the wires to the switches in the first picture are wrapped the wrong way around. The wire should be inserted so that tightening the screw pulls it in further. That helps make a tight connection. And they're way too long. Each wire should have a single 180 degree bend, and the free end shouldn't stick out past the switch.

The whole situation spooked me enough that I contacted an electrician (the son of a friend, although we've only really worked with him professionally for work in the house). According to them, RMDman was correct that I had managed to mix up the wires. The electrician said that there was an extra blue wire (I don't see one in any of the pictures on my phone) related to the dimmer that I hooked into the switch, and also that I'd managed to connect the receiving end of the overhead lights and the receiving end of the upstairs light onto that switch. He said that it was a pretty typical amateur mistake, and that he'd suspected that was the case when I contacted him, but couldn't figure out a good way to explain it via text such that I'd be able to do it on my own.

The key to avoiding this mix-up in the future is to label everything and take lots of pictures before any wires are removed. Label each switch/device A B C etc. Label each wire "top A", "Bottom A", "Left B", "Right B", etc, something that makes sense to you. Then remove only one device and replace it. Then remove and replace the next. Between the labeling, pictures, and only one device's wires loose at a time, you should be able to keep things sorted. Congrats on getting the wires fixed!

Acknowledged. I did take several pictures, and I thought that I had set the individual wires separately enough, but I guess the various pigtails defeated me as I unwound them and tried to attach them to the right places.
